# Windows 10x64 Home: Qualcomm WiFi range very short

Tags: windows-networking

I have a laptop that only connects to the WiFi router when in the same room.  My PC runs Windows 10x64 Home, and the adapter, a Qualcomm Atheros QCA 9565, is on 32 bit.  All my other devices work all over the house. Would changing the adapter to 64 correct the problem? and if so, how do I do that?

Comment: sorry:  I am running Win 10 Home, and the Network Adapter is Qualcomm Atheros (QCA 9565)

Comment: Please click [edit} and tell us how you know the Qualcomm QCA 9565 is 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ath-drivers.eu/64bit-inf-file-version-10.0.3.456-with-id-507.html has 32-bit and 64-bit INF files for your wireless adapter and Windows 10. Go into your Device Manager, find the Qualcomm device, right-click on it, and choose Uninstall Device. Close Device Manager. Go to the INF file for the 64 bit driver and right click on it then chose Install.

However, that may not solve your problem. The QCA is a five year old, 2.4GHz-only adapter, and if there are many other 2.4GHz routers nearby, they could be competing for bandwidth which reduces your effective range.

Other wireless devices likely run on 5GHz and, since there are many more channels for 5GHz, it's likely there's much less competition and therefore better throughput.